# iphone certificate problem

Tags: iphone, debugging, certificate

i have downloaded my certificate from developer portal and my provisioning file. i have added certificate into keychain access by clicking on it and added provisioning file into project. in my project i ve changed bundle identifier but when i want to debug over device it gives error;

"Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain"

when i look at the "code signing identity" in property of the project i do not see my certificate. there is only "iphone developer" (i think it is the default value and it does not work)

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your keychain doesn't have the private key of the certificate that you are trying to use. It would be on the Mac where the CSR(Certificate Signing Request) was generated . If it was generated on a different system, you need to export it in .p12 format, before you can use it on your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

"Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain" means in your keychain developer was not found . so first get certificate double click on it before that delete all key chain with same name ..after double tapping certificate keychain opens ..then use the same profile for that particular keychain and compile it

and also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400894/xcode-iphone-app-codesign-error)

Comment: have you checked that link which i provided?

Comment: problem will be with that certificate only and no other things and also change plist company name

Answer (score 0):

Update target info properties(identifier field) and code sign identities in build fields .clean all targets and build

Answer (score 0):

Pls install the .p12 file before installing provisioning profile..

Comment: where can i download .p12 file? btw since my certificate has expired i am trying to use my friends certificate.