# Xcode fails with "Code Signing" Error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-signing, xcrun

## Alternate Titles

(to aid search)

- Xcode 'CodeSign error: code signing is required'
- Xcode: iPhone app codesign error
- /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
- Jenkins fails with Code Sign error
- Command-line build fails with "provisioning profiles not found"
- Archiving Xcode project fails with provisioning error
- Missing signing certificates in Xcode

## Symptoms

The issue manifests it's self in one of several ways:

- Running your app on a device results in an error referencing "code signing" or "expired signing certificates"
- Building from the command line (or using a continuos integration system, such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org))   fails with a error similar to this:

  ```
    Check dependencies
    Code Sign error: No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates
  ```
- Archiving an app fails with "code signing" or "expired signing certificates" where a run or build work correctly.

Often the project may have several configurations and sometimes only a subset will fail. Deleting and regenerating provisioning profiles has no effect.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### [CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY verification script.](https://github.com/rjstelling/Xcode-Project-Validate)

Often in set ups that use version control the `project.pbxproj` can be merged in such a way that two `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` lines can be inserted. This seems to cause Xcode problems under certain situations (like command-line builds or archiving).

A tell-tail sign is lines similar to this in the `project.pbxproj` file (right-click on the project and select "Show Package Contents…")

```
"CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "iPhone Developer";
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = "iPhone Distribution";
```

Deleting one of these lines will let you select the correct value in Build Settings and the project should once again build correctly.

I have created simple script to help diagnose this issue it can be found here: https://github.com/rjstelling/Xcode-Project-Validate

Comment: I had the same issue and tried this as well but no luck.

Comment: This anwer has not worked for me, but this did: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/86161

Answer (score 1):

I got this code sign error with an Open Source Github project which I only wanted on my own device (not in store or anything) and I don't have a paid membership account.

In that case it's meanwhile (since XCode 7) possible to configure and allow your app as unsigned but trusted.

It's all explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4952845/828184

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which I could solve after a lot of wasted hours. So writing my solution here in case it helps someone.

My iOS app, which I have been developing and deploying/updating regularly for past 5 years, recently ran into a similar issue where final "Distribute App" via XCode Organizer started showing an error "Code Signing for MyAppName.app failed - see distribution logs for more information". The distribution logs have no information whatsoever.

After a lot of trial-and-error, I found that the certificate used for code signing had somehow gone corrupt. I [deleted](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev97211aeac) the certificate and it fixed the problem. Hope this helps someone.