# Xcode fails to build on iPad, gives code-signing error

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been researching this for a few days now and haven't been able to find a solution.

**Backstory:** I'm picking up a project that a previous worker left behind. I'm using a different Macbook to work on the project than was originally used, and I think that's an important part to my problem.

**Problem:** I've gotten the emulator to compile the program just fine, but when I try to install to a physical iPad, Xcode gives me a drop-down error that says

> "Failed to code sign 'app-name'. No valid signing identities matching
>   the teamID 'id-value' were found. [Cancel] [Fix Issue] "

When I click [Fix Issue], I get this message:

> "Could not generate key pair for CSR. [Cancel] [Done]".

When I Go to Xcode->Preferences->Accounts->ID->Signing Identities->iOS Development->Create, I get the same error: "Could not generate key pair for CSR. [OK]"

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962341/xcode-fails-with-code-signing-error) StackOVerflow response, and copied and ran their script and found two errors in my .proj file. I hoped it would fix the problem but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

Go to XCode->Preferences->Accounts
In the left bottom click on plus button and then "Add Apple ID", add your developer account credentials and click Sign In. Xcode will show all your teams, double click with which one you want to debug. In opened popup look at into Signing Identities tab->IOS Development, click create button under Action tab. Xcode will create new certificate for your mac. Add this team as a team for your project, then in your project's build settings set "Automatic" for Provisioning profile->Debug and "IOS Developer" for Code Signing Identity->Debug and you should be able to run app on device.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I forgot that I've tried this before (I'll add to the main description), and when I click 'create', I get the same error: "Could not generate key pair for CSR. [OK]"

Comment: Are you able to create certificate from developer portal? Maybe max available certificates count is over, so you need to revoke one of them?

Comment: I haven't done that t all. I get the feeling that whatever is required as far as certs and keys go, was taken care of by the previous developer. Since I'm using a different laptop, I might have to change some things that I'm not familiar with.